# return in coroutine with kotlin and suspend functions

Tags: function, kotlin, android-jetpack, suspend, withcontext

IN line return@withContext cachedCategories because it can't just be return cachedCategories only. Whats @withContext ?

Code full:

@Singleton
class FoodMenuRemoteSource @Inject constructor(private val foodMenuApi: FoodMenuApi) {

```
private var cachedCategories: List<FoodItem>? = null

suspend fun getFoodCategories(): List<FoodItem> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    var cachedCategories = cachedCategories
    if (cachedCategories == null) {
        cachedCategories = foodMenuApi.getFoodCategories().mapCategoriesToItems()
        this@FoodMenuRemoteSource.cachedCategories = cachedCategories
    }
    return@withContext cachedCategories
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to have a non-local return in a lambda. That's why @withContext is necessary. You see, the code block there is in fact not the body of the `getFoodCategories` but the lambda function that is the second argument of `withContext`. Also, the last expression in a lambda is automatically also the return value of it, so you can actually leave the `return@withContext` out completely like this

```
private var cachedCategories: List<FoodItem>? = null

suspend fun getFoodCategories(): List<FoodItem> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    var cachedCategories = cachedCategories
    if (cachedCategories == null) {
        cachedCategories = foodMenuApi.getFoodCategories().mapCategoriesToItems()
        this@FoodMenuRemoteSource.cachedCategories = cachedCategories
    }
    cachedCategories
}
```